# Display an moveable image layer in openlayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

so im trying since a month now to solve the above mentioned problem.

The idea is to display an image of a city map and drag it with the mouse or move it with a slider to the desired location.

That's my code so far:

```
var img_extent = null;
var overlay_image_layer;
var img_view_extent;
var img_source;
var map_view_extent;
var multiplier = 100;
var img_heigth;
var img_width;

var upload = document.getElementById('imageUpload');
upload.addEventListener('change', dateiupload);


function dateiupload(evt) {
    var _URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    var dateien = evt.target.files;
    var uploadDatei = dateien[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();

    var senddata = new Object();
    senddata.name = uploadDatei.name;
    senddata.date = uploadDatei.lastModified;
    senddata.size = uploadDatei.size;
    senddata.type = uploadDatei.type;


    reader.onload = function (theFileData) {
        senddata.fileData = theFileData.target.result;
    };

    objectURL = _URL.createObjectURL(uploadDatei);

    var image_html = new Image();
    image_html.src = objectURL;

    img_width = 0;
    img_heigth = 0;

    image_html.onload = function () {
        img_heigth = image_html.height;
        img_width = image_html.width;

        // get base image position
        // [minx, miny, maxx, maxy]
        map_view_extent = map.getView().calculateExtent(map.getSize());
        img_view_extent = [map_view_extent[0], map_view_extent[1], map_view_extent[0] + img_width * multiplier, map_view_extent[1] + img_heigth * multiplier];
        console.log(img_view_extent);

        img_source = new ol.source.ImageStatic({
            //projection: ol.proj.get('EPSG:3857'),
            url: objectURL,
            imageExtent: img_view_extent
        });

        overlay_image_layer =
            new ol.layer.Image({
                zIndex: 1,
                source: img_source
            });
        overlay_image_layer.addEventListener('change', function () {
            console.log('changed');
            map.render();
        });


        map.addLayer(overlay_image_layer);
    };
}

function change_on_x(event) {
    var temp = [img_view_extent[0] + (parseInt(event.value)), img_view_extent[1], img_view_extent[2] + (parseInt(event.value)), img_view_extent[3]]
    console.log(temp);
    img_source.set('imageExtent', temp);
    overlay_image_layer.setMap(map);
    overlay_image_layer.changed();

}
```

`function change_on_x` is called by an `<input type="range">`.

Can someone help me out here? :)

My map look like this:

```
var map =
new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [1492062.75385, 6895234.55805],
        zoom: 11
    }),
    layers: [
        //base_map_group_layer,
        //overlay_image_layer,
        OSM
    ],
    interactions: ol.interaction.defaults().extend([
        new ol.interaction.DragRotateAndZoom()
    ])
});
```

Comment: should image be the layer? it's weird with the concept of layer. you can move feature on layer but layer itself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. But is it possible to display an image as a feature that doesn’t change in size when you zoom in?

Comment: if the image is a feature, then it doesn't change the size when you zoom in/out